# Keycloak returning {"error":"Bearer token format error"} while getting clients by REST interface

Tags: windows-10, security, docker, curl, oauth2

Looking for a way to setup a keycloak env., create a new realm and populate with client/users to get a Minimal OAuth endpoint by using REST/CURL interface.

Keycloak returning {"error":"Bearer token format error"}

Im on Windows 10 Pro + Docker

Im not even reaching to get the client list from Master realm.

Im doing as documented on :

["keycloak-documentation/server_development/topics/admin-rest-api.adoc"](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-documentation/blob/master/server_development/topics/admin-rest-api.adoc)
.
And also on:

["Get clients belonging to the realm (GET /{realm}/clients)"](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-nodejs-admin-client#client)
.
["Authorization: bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUz..."](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#_initial_access_token)
.
["How are Keycloak roles managed?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47857926)
.

As way to reach:

[creating a realm via REST /auth/admin/realms](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/KEYCLOAK-4094?_sscc=t)
.
The script itself:

```
    mkdir test
    cd test
    npm install -g underscore-cli
    docker run --name keyclk01 -e KEYCLOAK_USER=admuser -e KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=admpass -p 8444:8443 -p 8081:8080 -p 9991:9990 jboss/keycloak
    docker restart keyclk01
    docker inspect --format "{{.NetworkSettings.IPAddress}}" keyclk01
    curl --proxy 127.0.0.1:8888 -k --url https://127.0.0.1:8444/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token -d "username=admuser&password=admpass&client_id=admin-cli&grant_type=password" > 01Raw.json
    type 01Raw.json | underscore pretty
    type 01Raw.json | underscore select ".access_token" | underscore reduce 0 > 02RawToken
    echo|set /p="Authorization: Bearer " > 03HeaderTpl
    type 03HeaderTpl 02RawToken > 04Header
    findstr "." 04Header > 05HeaderFix
    curl --proxy 127.0.0.1:8888 -k --url "https://127.0.0.1:8444/auth/admin/realms/master/clients" -H @05HeaderFix
    curl --proxy 127.0.0.1:8888 -k --url "https://127.0.0.1:8444/auth/admin/realms/master" -H @05HeaderFix
    curl --proxy 127.0.0.1:8888 -k --url "http://127.0.0.1:8444/auth/admin/realms/master/clients" -H @05HeaderFix -o responseFile01.txt
    curl --proxy 127.0.0.1:8888 -k --url "http://127.0.0.1:8444/auth/admin/realms/master" -H @05HeaderFix -o responseFile02.txt
    curl -k --url "http://127.0.0.1:8444/auth/admin/realms/master/clients" -H @05HeaderFix -o responseFile01.txt
    powerShell: Format-Hex responseFile01.txt ==>   0x15 0x03 0x03 0x00 0x02 0x02 0x50
    curl -k --url "http://127.0.0.1:8444/auth/admin/realms/master" -H @05HeaderFix -o responseFile02.txt
    powerShell: Format-Hex responseFile02.txt ==>   0x15 0x03 0x03 0x00 0x02 0x02 0x50
```

The http messages got with Fiddler:
(The "This buggy server did not return headers" looks be from Fiddler proxy)

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
POST https://127.0.0.1:8444/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:8444
User-Agent: curl/7.55.1
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 73
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

username=admuser&password=admpass&client_id=admin-cli&grant_type=password
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: no-store
Set-Cookie: KC_RESTART=; Version=1; Expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:10 GMT; Max-Age=0; Path=/auth/realms/master/; HttpOnly
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 1783
Date: Wed, 06 Nov 2019 17:28:52 GMT

{"access_token":"eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJ0RF9JNHY2dHJtWnBMQTg4aFU2V1ZXb0dCcVdwSm0xRW51ajVEWjVuQWE4In0.eyJqdGkiOiI0MTQ4MzgyNi1kOGMyLTQ5ZmEtOWQ1My0xNjY3NjIwM2IzMmIiLCJleHAiOjE1NzMwNjEzOTIsIm5iZiI6MCwiaWF0IjoxNTczMDYxMzMyLCJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovLzEyNy4wLjAuMTo4NDQ0L2F1dGgvcmVhbG1zL21hc3RlciIsInN1YiI6IjA2ODRjZDJmLWU4YWItNDEzNy1hNDMzLTAyNWE1OTcyOTdjOCIsInR5cCI6IkJlYXJlciIsImF6cCI6ImFkbWluLWNsaSIsImF1dGhfdGltZSI6MCwic2Vzc2lvbl9zdGF0ZSI6IjYwNWVkZTE1LWU4Y2EtNDQ1OS1iYjQ0LTliMzQ5NzA3NzUwZSIsImFjciI6IjEiLCJzY29wZSI6InByb2ZpbGUgZW1haWwiLCJlbWFpbF92ZXJpZmllZCI6ZmFsc2UsInByZWZlcnJlZF91c2VybmFtZSI6ImFkbXVzZXIifQ.I-snNpKcCFBmhbF5pQox_FZx9SVVhxZppYz3xe0mVgBRIysc8q80T1hpwU15D_mhSQ4UxA875dwYtmq6UHVEG5qbPpCmAqV3YZXfCm2MtSyXiQflibIf6JemoON3QL645N--Y3nFI3mTu5CN9IUyvlXKR4f-AwmxJW1OhyjoyGiVLhJ3MMSKdp2x7MCPBQyuSKdIQLEyeCpWuGj6bviG2jm44xlsigKjGkW7X13bs-CqNwODPdOISX_4cxNnQhClmI6mpoXFW9fhYwLpOdx8vG3gi_5P-IuX6oCNUTyFnkpfOTmbacfG7bqUUwcPeUcjHkQdm9QuJWYmqffWTiJN-w","expires_in":60,"refresh_expires_in":1800,"refresh_token":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICIzOGFmYTg4OC01ZWQ4LTRhZTQtYTU3My00OGNmODRlNDA4YTEifQ.eyJqdGkiOiJlZTE4NGNhYy0xZmY0LTRiNTMtYTBmNy1mYWQ5N2FjZDgwZjIiLCJleHAiOjE1NzMwNjMxMzIsIm5iZiI6MCwiaWF0IjoxNTczMDYxMzMyLCJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovLzEyNy4wLjAuMTo4NDQ0L2F1dGgvcmVhbG1zL21hc3RlciIsImF1ZCI6Imh0dHBzOi8vMTI3LjAuMC4xOjg0NDQvYXV0aC9yZWFsbXMvbWFzdGVyIiwic3ViIjoiMDY4NGNkMmYtZThhYi00MTM3LWE0MzMtMDI1YTU5NzI5N2M4IiwidHlwIjoiUmVmcmVzaCIsImF6cCI6ImFkbWluLWNsaSIsImF1dGhfdGltZSI6MCwic2Vzc2lvbl9zdGF0ZSI6IjYwNWVkZTE1LWU4Y2EtNDQ1OS1iYjQ0LTliMzQ5NzA3NzUwZSIsInNjb3BlIjoicHJvZmlsZSBlbWFpbCJ9.j9-VpOQ8qEmz8KfctOz6tKdlUmOuuUFgeR6unbhdjOc","token_type":"bearer","not-before-policy":0,"session_state":"605ede15-e8ca-4459-bb44-9b349707750e","scope":"profile email"}
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
============================================================================================================
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
GET https://127.0.0.1:8444/auth/admin/realms/master/clients HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:8444
User-Agent: curl/7.55.1
Accept: */*
Authorization: Bearer "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJ0RF9JNHY2dHJtWnBMQTg4aFU2V1ZXb0dCcVdwSm0xRW51ajVEWjVuQWE4In0.eyJqdGkiOiI0MTQ4MzgyNi1kOGMyLTQ5ZmEtOWQ1My0xNjY3NjIwM2IzMmIiLCJleHAiOjE1NzMwNjEzOTIsIm5iZiI6MCwiaWF0IjoxNTczMDYxMzMyLCJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovLzEyNy4wLjAuMTo4NDQ0L2F1dGgvcmVhbG1zL21hc3RlciIsInN1YiI6IjA2ODRjZDJmLWU4YWItNDEzNy1hNDMzLTAyNWE1OTcyOTdjOCIsInR5cCI6IkJlYXJlciIsImF6cCI6ImFkbWluLWNsaSIsImF1dGhfdGltZSI6MCwic2Vzc2lvbl9zdGF0ZSI6IjYwNWVkZTE1LWU4Y2EtNDQ1OS1iYjQ0LTliMzQ5NzA3NzUwZSIsImFjciI6IjEiLCJzY29wZSI6InByb2ZpbGUgZW1haWwiLCJlbWFpbF92ZXJpZmllZCI6ZmFsc2UsInByZWZlcnJlZF91c2VybmFtZSI6ImFkbXVzZXIifQ.I-snNpKcCFBmhbF5pQox_FZx9SVVhxZppYz3xe0mVgBRIysc8q80T1hpwU15D_mhSQ4UxA875dwYtmq6UHVEG5qbPpCmAqV3YZXfCm2MtSyXiQflibIf6JemoON3QL645N--Y3nFI3mTu5CN9IUyvlXKR4f-AwmxJW1OhyjoyGiVLhJ3MMSKdp2x7MCPBQyuSKdIQLEyeCpWuGj6bviG2jm44xlsigKjGkW7X13bs-CqNwODPdOISX_4cxNnQhClmI6mpoXFW9fhYwLpOdx8vG3gi_5P-IuX6oCNUTyFnkpfOTmbacfG7bqUUwcPeUcjHkQdm9QuJWYmqffWTiJN-w"


------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 37
Date: Wed, 06 Nov 2019 17:28:53 GMT

{"error":"Bearer token format error"}
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
============================================================================================================
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
GET https://127.0.0.1:8444/auth/admin/realms/master HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:8444
User-Agent: curl/7.55.1
Accept: */*
Authorization: Bearer "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJ0RF9JNHY2dHJtWnBMQTg4aFU2V1ZXb0dCcVdwSm0xRW51ajVEWjVuQWE4In0.eyJqdGkiOiI0MTQ4MzgyNi1kOGMyLTQ5ZmEtOWQ1My0xNjY3NjIwM2IzMmIiLCJleHAiOjE1NzMwNjEzOTIsIm5iZiI6MCwiaWF0IjoxNTczMDYxMzMyLCJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovLzEyNy4wLjAuMTo4NDQ0L2F1dGgvcmVhbG1zL21hc3RlciIsInN1YiI6IjA2ODRjZDJmLWU4YWItNDEzNy1hNDMzLTAyNWE1OTcyOTdjOCIsInR5cCI6IkJlYXJlciIsImF6cCI6ImFkbWluLWNsaSIsImF1dGhfdGltZSI6MCwic2Vzc2lvbl9zdGF0ZSI6IjYwNWVkZTE1LWU4Y2EtNDQ1OS1iYjQ0LTliMzQ5NzA3NzUwZSIsImFjciI6IjEiLCJzY29wZSI6InByb2ZpbGUgZW1haWwiLCJlbWFpbF92ZXJpZmllZCI6ZmFsc2UsInByZWZlcnJlZF91c2VybmFtZSI6ImFkbXVzZXIifQ.I-snNpKcCFBmhbF5pQox_FZx9SVVhxZppYz3xe0mVgBRIysc8q80T1hpwU15D_mhSQ4UxA875dwYtmq6UHVEG5qbPpCmAqV3YZXfCm2MtSyXiQflibIf6JemoON3QL645N--Y3nFI3mTu5CN9IUyvlXKR4f-AwmxJW1OhyjoyGiVLhJ3MMSKdp2x7MCPBQyuSKdIQLEyeCpWuGj6bviG2jm44xlsigKjGkW7X13bs-CqNwODPdOISX_4cxNnQhClmI6mpoXFW9fhYwLpOdx8vG3gi_5P-IuX6oCNUTyFnkpfOTmbacfG7bqUUwcPeUcjHkQdm9QuJWYmqffWTiJN-w"


------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 37
Date: Wed, 06 Nov 2019 17:28:53 GMT

{"error":"Bearer token format error"}
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
============================================================================================================
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
GET http://127.0.0.1:8444/auth/admin/realms/master/clients HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:8444
User-Agent: curl/7.55.1
Accept: */*
Connection: Keep-Alive
Authorization: Bearer "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJ0RF9JNHY2dHJtWnBMQTg4aFU2V1ZXb0dCcVdwSm0xRW51ajVEWjVuQWE4In0.eyJqdGkiOiI0MTQ4MzgyNi1kOGMyLTQ5ZmEtOWQ1My0xNjY3NjIwM2IzMmIiLCJleHAiOjE1NzMwNjEzOTIsIm5iZiI6MCwiaWF0IjoxNTczMDYxMzMyLCJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovLzEyNy4wLjAuMTo4NDQ0L2F1dGgvcmVhbG1zL21hc3RlciIsInN1YiI6IjA2ODRjZDJmLWU4YWItNDEzNy1hNDMzLTAyNWE1OTcyOTdjOCIsInR5cCI6IkJlYXJlciIsImF6cCI6ImFkbWluLWNsaSIsImF1dGhfdGltZSI6MCwic2Vzc2lvbl9zdGF0ZSI6IjYwNWVkZTE1LWU4Y2EtNDQ1OS1iYjQ0LTliMzQ5NzA3NzUwZSIsImFjciI6IjEiLCJzY29wZSI6InByb2ZpbGUgZW1haWwiLCJlbWFpbF92ZXJpZmllZCI6ZmFsc2UsInByZWZlcnJlZF91c2VybmFtZSI6ImFkbXVzZXIifQ.I-snNpKcCFBmhbF5pQox_FZx9SVVhxZppYz3xe0mVgBRIysc8q80T1hpwU15D_mhSQ4UxA875dwYtmq6UHVEG5qbPpCmAqV3YZXfCm2MtSyXiQflibIf6JemoON3QL645N--Y3nFI3mTu5CN9IUyvlXKR4f-AwmxJW1OhyjoyGiVLhJ3MMSKdp2x7MCPBQyuSKdIQLEyeCpWuGj6bviG2jm44xlsigKjGkW7X13bs-CqNwODPdOISX_4cxNnQhClmI6mpoXFW9fhYwLpOdx8vG3gi_5P-IuX6oCNUTyFnkpfOTmbacfG7bqUUwcPeUcjHkQdm9QuJWYmqffWTiJN-w"


------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
HTTP/1.0 200 This buggy server did not return headers

 P
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
============================================================================================================
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
GET http://127.0.0.1:8444/auth/admin/realms/master HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:8444
User-Agent: curl/7.55.1
Accept: */*
Connection: Keep-Alive
Authorization: Bearer "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJ0RF9JNHY2dHJtWnBMQTg4aFU2V1ZXb0dCcVdwSm0xRW51ajVEWjVuQWE4In0.eyJqdGkiOiI0MTQ4MzgyNi1kOGMyLTQ5ZmEtOWQ1My0xNjY3NjIwM2IzMmIiLCJleHAiOjE1NzMwNjEzOTIsIm5iZiI6MCwiaWF0IjoxNTczMDYxMzMyLCJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovLzEyNy4wLjAuMTo4NDQ0L2F1dGgvcmVhbG1zL21hc3RlciIsInN1YiI6IjA2ODRjZDJmLWU4YWItNDEzNy1hNDMzLTAyNWE1OTcyOTdjOCIsInR5cCI6IkJlYXJlciIsImF6cCI6ImFkbWluLWNsaSIsImF1dGhfdGltZSI6MCwic2Vzc2lvbl9zdGF0ZSI6IjYwNWVkZTE1LWU4Y2EtNDQ1OS1iYjQ0LTliMzQ5NzA3NzUwZSIsImFjciI6IjEiLCJzY29wZSI6InByb2ZpbGUgZW1haWwiLCJlbWFpbF92ZXJpZmllZCI6ZmFsc2UsInByZWZlcnJlZF91c2VybmFtZSI6ImFkbXVzZXIifQ.I-snNpKcCFBmhbF5pQox_FZx9SVVhxZppYz3xe0mVgBRIysc8q80T1hpwU15D_mhSQ4UxA875dwYtmq6UHVEG5qbPpCmAqV3YZXfCm2MtSyXiQflibIf6JemoON3QL645N--Y3nFI3mTu5CN9IUyvlXKR4f-AwmxJW1OhyjoyGiVLhJ3MMSKdp2x7MCPBQyuSKdIQLEyeCpWuGj6bviG2jm44xlsigKjGkW7X13bs-CqNwODPdOISX_4cxNnQhClmI6mpoXFW9fhYwLpOdx8vG3gi_5P-IuX6oCNUTyFnkpfOTmbacfG7bqUUwcPeUcjHkQdm9QuJWYmqffWTiJN-w"


------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
HTTP/1.0 200 This buggy server did not return headers

 P
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
============================================================================================================
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do exactly what you are describe, but I use Python to parse the JSON.  Here is what I do:

```
ACCESS_TOKEN=$(curl -s -k -d 'client_id=admin-cli' \
                          -d 'username=admin' \
                          -d "password=$KEYCLOAK_PW" \
                          -d 'grant_type=password' \
                         "https://${KEYCLOAK_SERVER}/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token" | python -c '
import json,sys;keycloak_data=json.load(sys.stdin);print keycloak_data["access_token"]')
```

Create the Realm:

```
cat <<! | curl -k -s \
        -X POST \
        -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
        -H "Authorization: bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN" \
        --data-binary @- "https://${KEYCLOAK_SERVER}/auth/admin/realms"
{"enabled":true,"id":"myrealm","realm":"myrealm"}
!
```

Add in the client

```
cat <<! | curl -s -k \
        -X POST \
        -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
        -H "Authorization: bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN" \
        --data-binary @- "https://${KEYCLOAK_SERVER}/auth/admin/realms/myrealm/clients"
{
                "clientId": "$INSTANCE_NAME",
                "clientAuthenticatorType": "client-secret",
                "protocol": "openid-connect",
                "fullScopeAllowed": false,
                "authorizationServicesEnabled": true,
                "serviceAccountsEnabled": true,
                "redirectUris" : [ "https://$INSTANCE/*" ],
                "publicClient": false,
                "enabled": true
                }
}
!
```

Retrieve the CLIENT_ID

```
CLIENT_ID=$(curl -s -k \
        -X GET \
        -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
        -H "Authorization: bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN" \
        "https://${KEYCLOAK_SERVER}/auth/admin/realms/myrealm/clients" | python -c '
import json,sys,os;keycloak_data=json.load(sys.stdin)
CLIENTID=os.environ["INSTANCE_NAME"]
for c in keycloak_data:
    if c["clientId"]==CLIENTID:
        print c["id"]
        sys.exit()
')
```

Maybe this will help if you still need it, or if someone else needs it.

Answer (score 1):

The Keycloak project is almost discontinued, they have now the Identity Access Management (IAM) that is proprietary.

The Keycloak itself was always broken and many of REST endpoints doesn't work and return nonsense responses as you can see by yourself even following strictly the documentation.

The answer is that because Keycloak is broken even following the documentation is imposible to do what you want.

My advice is that you try alternatives as you can find [here](https://gist.github.com/bmaupin/6878fae9abcb63ef43f8ac9b9de8fafd).

Comment: Looks like, Keycloak 8.0.1 released on Monday, December 02 2019 https://www.keycloak.org/2019/12/keycloak-801-released.html